# Microsoft Bot Framework - Direct Line AND Skype Channel - Combobox/Dropdown List

Tags: combobox, botframework, dropdown, direct-line-botframework

It doesn't look like Adaptive cards are supported in Direct Line or Skype channels. What is the best option to show Dropdown list/Combobox in Direct Line channel?

Comment: There is no native dropdown menu other than in adaptive cards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Direct Line`, then you control the UI of the bot and how things are being rendered in your custom channel. Probably you can use the ChannelData property (in C#) to send custom data that later you channel can understand, and react to it by rendering a DropDown.